# StreetViewPanoramaView inside Nested scroll view not working

Tags: android, google-street-view

I have two fragments in the activity which is inside the scroll view. I am able to display both but when I want to pinch to zoom or move the street view it's not working properly. I there any solution to make it work.

Here is the activity view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    // fragment 1 related view
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    // fragment 2 related view
    <com.google.android.gms.maps.StreetViewPanoramaView
        android:id="@+id/streetViewPanorama"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/streetView" />

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken a `CustomStreetViewPanoramaView` class which extends the `StreetViewPanoramaView` class then requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent to true and requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent to false.

```
class CustomStreetViewPanoramaView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : StreetViewPanoramaView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        when (event?.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                parent.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                parent.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false)
            }
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event)
    }

}
```

Then in the XML instead of using `com.google.android.gms.maps.StreetViewPanoramaView` replace it with your custom class with package (`com.yourpackage.name.CustomStreetViewPanoramaView`) like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    // fragment 1 related view
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    // fragment 2 related view
    <com.yourpackage.name.CustomStreetViewPanoramaView
        android:id="@+id/streetViewPanorama"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/streetView" />

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

It's working as expected now. May it useful for someone.